# MySQL After Update trigger updating everything

Tags: mysql

So I have an after update trigger which if the field changes it would update the data of a column in another table, however, turns out it would be updating the entire column for all the rows.

This trigger is in the 'orders' table:

```
IF (NEW.status != OLD.status) THEN
    UPDATE orderep SET status = (SELECT NEW.status FROM orders WHERE orders.orderNumber = OLD.orderNumber);
    UPDATE order_audit SET status = (SELECT NEW.status FROM orders WHERE orderNumber = OLD.orderNumber);
    END IF;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a where clause on the UPDATE statement for the orderrep and order_audit tables and the lookup on orders seems to be redundant. Assuming orderrep and order_audit ref the orders table:

```
IF (NEW.status != OLD.status) THEN
UPDATE orderep SET status = NEW.status WHERE orderrep.order_id = NEW.id ;
UPDATE order_audit SET status = NEW.status WHERE order_audit.order_id = NEW.id ;
END IF
```